# Get actual offset of Android Dialog Window

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-window

Here is a simple alert dialog. Default gravity is center

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Sample Alert")
                        .setMessage("This is sample alert dialog")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null);

                AlertDialog alert = alertBuild.create();
                alert.show();
```

I want to get the actual distance of the dialog window from the top of the screen.

I tried setting the below attribute.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = alert.getWindow().getAttributes();
                attributes.y = 205;
                alert.getWindow().setAttributes(attributes);
```

I am able to get the window's distance from top[alert.getWindow().getAttributes().y].

But when I set the gravity as any of the below, x and y become 0.

```
attributes.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
attributes.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoONL.png)

Specifically not working for **android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog**

Can someone help with how do I get the actual dialog window distance from the top of the screen?

Comment: You might try using `View#getLocationOnScreen()` with `alert.getWindow().getDecorView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. The value comes 0 and not the actual offset from the top/left of the screen.

Comment: It works as expected for me. Make sure to use `getLocationOnScreen()`, not `getLocationInWindow()`. Also make sure that the `Dialog` is actually laid out before trying to get the location.

Comment: `BottomSheetDialog` is not a normal `Dialog` implementation. It actually fills the screen; it just has a transparent background. It you actually want the location of your `View` rather than the whole `Dialog`, you would use `getLocationOnScreen()` with your `View` instead of the decor `View`.